# Bash Script pipe multiple commands to one email

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I wanna write the output of various commands as an email.
I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

(echo $(date); echo $(top);sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y)  | mail -s "Updated!" xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com -a "From: UpdateNotify<xxxxxxxx@gmail.com>";
```

The script is infinite. :/

How can I do that? I need the date,top output and the update logs in one email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the right way to do it, the issue is with `echo $(top)`. `top` is an interactive application so never returns.

You should look to use `ps` instead to list the current processes running.

Comment: It is the right way to do it. It can also be formatted nicer with newline after the initial `(` and newline before the closing `)` and indentation in between. Then every command can be on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

jas_raj answer is correct, however if you like `top`'s output you can run in batch mode: `top -bn 1` this will make top exit right after it runs once.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `cron-apt` and `nullmailer` to send mails after system update.